# Error when using callback function with f2py

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I'm trying to pass a python function to a f2py generated function. I can not figure out how to do this when the python function's input and output is an array. (I'm new to f2py!)

Here is my fortran code (num_Dg.f):

```
     subroutine num_Dg(func,U,jacob,n)
        double precision, intent(in) :: U(n)
        double precision, intent(out) :: jacob(n,n)
        double precision Up(n), Um(n)
        double precision g_valp(n),g_valm(n)
        double precision :: rel_eps = 2.e-5
        double precision eps
        integer i, j
        external func

        eps = minval(U)*rel_eps

        do j=1,n
          do i=1,n
            if (i .eq. j) then
            Up(i) = U(i)+(eps)
            Um(i) = U(i)-(eps)
            else
            Up(i) = 0
            Um(i) = 0
            endif
          enddo
          call func(Up,g_valp,n)
          call func(Um,g_valm,n)
          do i=1,n
            jacob(i,j) = 0.0
            jacob(i,j) = (g_valp(i)-g_valm(i))/(2*eps)
          enddo
        enddo
      end subroutine
```

I use f2py to compile: `f2py -c num_Dg.f -m num_Dg`. It compiles without errors. But when import the function into python I get this:

```
>>> from num_Dg import num_dg
>>> print(num_dg.__doc__)
jacob = num_dg(func,u,[n,func_extra_args])

Wrapper for ``num_dg``.

Parameters
----------
func : call-back function
u : input rank-1 array('d') with bounds (n)

Other Parameters
----------------
func_extra_args : input tuple, optional
    Default: ()
n : input int, optional
    Default: len(u)

Returns
-------
jacob : rank-2 array('d') with bounds (n,n)

Notes
-----
Call-back functions::

  def func(up,gvalp,[n]): return 
  Required arguments:
    up : input rank-1 array('d') with bounds (n)
    gvalp : input rank-1 array('d') with bounds (n)
  Optional arguments:
    n : input int, optional
    Default: len(up)
```

There is a problem with the callback function `func`. The input should be array `U`, and the output should be `gval`. Instead, both `U` and `gval` are inputs, with no output.

I'm assuming this is why the following python script returns garbage:

```
import num_Dg

def func(x):
    return [x[0]**2,x[1],x[2]]

val = [0.2,0.1,0.1]

num_Dg.num_dg(func,val)
```

How should I change my fortran subroutine so that the callback function works properly? Any advice is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, I suggest to take the [tour]. Did you try writing an interface block for the function? When it is external, the function signature is not really exactly defined. F2py likely tries to infer from the call somehow.

Comment: You use `Up` in both calls to `func`, whereas it looks like you should use `Up` and `Um` in turn. Also, why don't you call `func` as `gvalp = func(Up)` ? Or include the `n` in the arguments? A function declared as external has zero checks on its syntax, this can be limiting.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. `Up` should be replaced with `Um` in the second call of `func`. I changed the code so that `g_valp = func(Up,n)`, where n is the dimension of `Up`. Now, when I do `print(num_dg.__doc__)`, I get a format of the callback function that looks sensible. But still, when I call the program from python i don't get a good result. from using print statements in the fortran program, It looks like the reason is because the call to func isn't working properly. @VladimirF, I used f2py to generate a interface block for the function.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out. I think the reason why it wasn't working was because I was missing the line `cf2py   intent(out), depend(n) :: g_valp`. The script can be compiled in the normal way with f2py: `f2py -c num_Dg.f -m num_Dg`

```
      subroutine num_Dg(U,jacob,n)
cf2py   intent(callback) func
        external func
        integer n
        double precision :: U(n)
        double precision :: jacob(n,n)
        double precision Up(n), Um(n)
        double precision g_valp(n),g_valm(n)
        double precision :: rel_eps = 2.e-5
        double precision eps
        integer i, j

cf2py   intent(in,copy), depend(n) :: U
cf2py   intent(hide) :: n
cf2py   intent(out), depend(n) :: jacob
cf2py   intent(out), depend(n) :: g_valp

        eps = minval(U)*rel_eps
        do j=1,n
          do i=1,n
            if (i .eq. j) then
            Up(i) = U(i)+(eps)
            Um(i) = U(i)-(eps)
            else
            Up(i) = 0
            Um(i) = 0
            endif
          enddo

          call func(n,Up,g_valp)
          call func(n,Um,g_valm)

          do i=1,n
            jacob(i,j) = (g_valp(i)-g_valm(i))/(2*eps)

          enddo

        enddo
      end subroutine
```